# C++ template specialization for map-like types

Tags: c++, templates

I want to define a generic function for printing contents of `std::map` like types. My initial attempt is a function like this:

```
template <class K, class V>
inline void PrintCollection(const std::map<K,V>& map,
                            const char* separator="\n",
                            const char* arrow="->",
                            const char* optcstr="") {
  typedef typename std::map<K,V>::const_iterator iter_type;
  std::cout << optcstr;
  for (iter_type begin = map.begin(), it = begin, end = map.end();
       it != end; ++it) {
    if (it != begin) {
      std::cout << separator;
    }
    std::cout << it->first << arrow << it->second;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

which works fine. When I try to generalize this function one more step, i.e. make it work for `std::multimap` type, compiler becomes angry. I tried several ways to make `std::map` generic in the function definition, such as:

```
template <class M, class K, class V>
inline void PrintCollection(const M<K,V>& map,
                            const char* separator="\n",
                            const char* arrow="->",
                            const char* optcstr="") {
  typedef typename M<K,V>::const_iterator iter_type;
  std::cout << optcstr;
  for (iter_type begin = map.begin(), it = begin, end = map.end();
       it != end; ++it) {
    if (it != begin) {
      std::cout << separator;
    }
    std::cout << it->first << arrow << it->second;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

with no success.

How can I generalize this function as I defined above?

To be more clear, I have already a function defined for vector-like classes defined before this function. It is like

```
template <class T>
inline void PrintCollection(const T& collection,
                            const char* separator="\n",
                            const char* optcstr="") {
  typedef typename T::const_iterator iter_type;

  std::cout << optcstr;

  for (iter_type begin = collection.begin(), it = begin, end = collection.end();
       it != end;
       ++it) {
    if (it != begin) {
      std::cout << separator;
    }
    std::cout << *it;
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

So what I want to achieve it to make this function specialized to map-like classes. I'm pretty new in C++, so I don't know the exact term for this kind of stuff. Is this called "template specialization"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like the stdlib does and use iterators in your algorithm interfaces. This is the most generic solution.

```
template<class Iter>
void PrintCollection(Iter first, Iter last,
                     const char* separator="\n",
                     const char* arrow="->",
                     const char* optcstr="") 
{
    typedef Iter iter_type;
    std::cout << optcstr;
    for (iter_type begin = first, it = begin, end = last;
        it != end; ++it) {
    if (it != begin) {
        std::cout << separator;
    }
    std::cout << it->first << arrow << it->second;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    vector<pair<int, int>> collection;
    map<int, int> collection2;
    pair<int, int> collection3[3];

    PrintCollection(begin(collection), end(collection));
    PrintCollection(begin(collection2), end(collection2));
    PrintCollection(begin(collection3), end(collection3));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is fairly simple.

There is no dependency on typenames `K` and `V` in the function. So remove them and make a general template. It can be used for both `map` and `multimap`:

```
template <class AnyMap>
void PrintCollection(const AnyMap& map,
  ...
{
  typedef typename AnyMap::const_iterator iter_type;
```

On side note, with `template`s, you don't need `inline` keyword.

Comment: I want to write this PrintCollection function work for any container type, such as for std::vector, etc. So the code I pasted was actually a template specialization for map-like classes. Before that, I have another function which fors for sequential containers.

Comment: @Haldun, all containers don't have `first` and `second` data member inside them. If you remove the code specific to that, my solution will work for any container. Here is a demo for [map/multimap](http://ideone.com/A7VFP).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a template-template parameter

```
template<template<class, class> class M, class K, class V>
inline void PrintCollection(const M<K, V>& map, /* rest as before */)
{
    // rest as before
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> m1;
    std::multi_map<int, int> m2;

    // fill both maps

    PrintCollection(m1);
    PrintCollection(m2);
}
```

But as hansmaad is pointing out, you could also use a pair of iterators instead of the container as parameter. In general, you would prefer that solution if your `PrintCollection` is very generic and does not make use of the fact that it has a `Key` and `Value` type. OTOH, if your `PrintCollection` also needs to print that information in some future version, then you might want to use a template-template parameter that takes those two types as parameters.

Comment: A map has actually four template parameters, some of which are defaulted.

Comment: @BoPersson Good point. It could be worked around with a template alias probably, but maybe not worth the trouble.